iPhone simulator can not send request to one specific endpoint
I am developing a Flutter app which sends http requests to my express.js rest api which runs on my server. It was working fine until yesterday when out of the blue it stopped working. All the request made to that api only from my network timeout regardless of the device. (Even physical devices can't make)
Sometimes when i restart the computer, i can make the requests but it stops working after a while.
Here is an example post request within the app
final response = await dio.post("/gwpdt",
       options: Options(
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       ),
       data: {"wpid": wpid}
);

Here is the express.js endpoint for it
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const token = extractJwtFromBearer(req.headers.authorization);

    if (isTokenExpired(token)) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'jwt_expired', message: 'Jwt is expired' });
    } else {
        const verification = verifyJwt(token);

        if (verification.verified === false) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: verification.err });
        } else {
            const wpid = req.body.wpid;
            const user_id = verification.decoded.user_id;

            const queryResult = await db.query('queryHere');
            if (queryResult.rowCount) {
                const { result, error } = await func(wpid);   
                if (error) {
                    res.status(400).json({ message: error });
                } else {
                    res.json(result);
                }
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authorization error!' });
            }
        }
    }
});

API uses cors and helmet npm packages but i didn't do any settings, they are default imports.
Postman gives: Error: Request timed out.
this website gives: Operation timeout error code 10028.
this website works fine.
Any help is appreciated,
thanks in advance.
Note: Server has no ssl sertificate

Well, if postman cannot reach the site, this is probably not an issue with your app or the iOS simulator but with your network configuration/network connection ...

What kind of settings can cause this type of behaviour?
